# The item X was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project and I drag and drop an image to my Android resources folder, then I copied it and pasted it in my UWP Project, but the image doesnt display, so I changed its build action to Content, but it displays the error:

`Error      The item "obj\Debug\MainPage.xaml.g.cs" was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the "Sources" parameter. XamaTask.Android`
Im not sure if its related with the images, but after I duplicated,renamed and changed that build action property the error started to show , I also deleted the images and renamed more times again and checked my Android.csproject but I dont find any duplicated item.
**Edit**
I have found the file that have the error, but Again, I dont find any duplicated, here it is the code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute("XamaTask.Droid.MainPage.xaml", "MainPage.xaml", typeof(global::XamaTask.MainPage))]

namespace XamaTask {


    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("C:\\Users\\M\\source\\repos\\XamaTask\\XamaTask\\XamaTask\\MainPage.xaml")]
    public partial class MainPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you delete the obj and bin folders and rebuild?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Deleting Obj and Bin Folders will corrupt the project, no?

Comment: No, those and everything in it will be generated with the next build

Comment: @GeraldVersluis So, Are You Saying That I need to delete it, and when I rebuild it again, it will be regenerated again automatically?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @GeraldVersluis No, I have deleted them but it stills with the error.

Comment: Make sure you close the g.cs file in visual studio before cleaning/deleting obj en bin folders.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this after a bad merge. I edited the .csproj and removed the duplicate line that included the same .cs file twice.